# Generate extra records in Select statement Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to generate records during my Select statement for each unique F_ID for period of 12/31/2012 to "STARTDT of the first record for that F_ID" in ascending order with a status of FB

( i.e. for 15960 I want a record with

ID = 15960 ; Status = 'FB'; Startdt = 12/31/2012; ENDDT a= 11/14/2013 )

Note : If there is already a record prior to 12/31/2012 then no need to generate for that F_ID

(for example : 16022 has a record from 1/1/2010 so no record is needed for this F_ID)

```
F_ID     STATUS     STARTDT     ENDDT
-----  ---------  ---------  ---------
15960   NF      11/14/2013  3/3/2014
15960   FB      3/3/2014    12/31/9999
16022   DF      1/1/2010    3/5/2013
16022   FB      3/5/2013    12/31/9999
```

I remember seeing Model clause using UPSERT , Is there any other way without using complex Model clause, help is really appreciated.If not then how do I go about using Model clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you need the answer in plsql.

Based on the following conditions:

1. Select records whose min startdt is greater than 12/31/2012
2. Out of which select records which contains 'FB' as status

Following is the sql:

```
select f_id, 'FB' status, '31-Dec-2012' startdt, min(startdt) enddt from ftest
where f_id in
(select f_id from ftest where f_id in(select oq.f_id from ftest oq where
oq.startdt =(
select min(iq.startdt) from ftest iq 
where iq.startdt > to_date('31-DEC-2012','DD-MON-YY')
and iq.f_id=oq.f_id
and iq.startdt = (select min(startdt) from ftest where f_id=iq.f_id)
)) and status='FB') GROUP BY F_ID;
```

Also, check [this sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72221/12)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your time and effort. I just have to union to the main table you created to get basically all the records for that id.There are almost million such records,I will check how the performance will be if querying the same table multiple times as you have shown.But really appreciate your help.Thanks again Sir.

Comment: I too was thinking on similar lines,but was wondering if I can achieve without Union. Also, yea I didn't want to use PLSQL